# Using parent's constructor with prototype.js

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have been a programmer for years now. Javascript seems to be the most quirky language I have came across so I am very stuck as to how I can perform this task.

My question is how can I override the constructor of a parent with prototype. For example:

This works:

```
function Superclass(arg1, arg2) {
alert(this.arg1);
alert(this.arg2);
}

function Subclass() {

}
Subclass.prototype = new Superclass();

//I am instituting the superclass as I do not know how to override the perant's method
var SubclassInstance = new Superclass("arg1", "arg2");
```

This won't work though:

```
function Superclass(arg1, arg2) {
alert(this.arg1);
alert(this.arg2);
}

function Subclass() {
//for this example I have not coded any behaviour for the subclass
}
Subclass.prototype = new Superclass();

//I am instituting the superclass as I do not know how to override the perant's method
var SubclassInstance = new Subclass("arg1", "arg2");
```

Thanks all

Comment: Could it be that your are confusing prototypal inheritance (a concept in JavaScript) with Prototype.js (a library)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call parent constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617780/how-to-call-parent-constructor)

Comment: No confusion between Javascript and prototype. I was just using this as an example because of my lack of experience with JS and prototype. Thanks btw. I will check this out.

Comment: Either way, your example has nothing to do with Prototype.js.

Answer (score 0):

To re use parent constructor you can do

```
      Parent.call(this,args)
```

What args can be and an explanation about constructor functions and their prototype can be found here: [Prototypical inheritance - writing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711)