# How to get javascript parents constructors (class ,objects)

Tags: javascript, oop

To check if the constructor is a constructor of an object1 , do :

```
     object1=new MyConstructor();
     object1 instanceof MyConstructor === true
```

if **MyConstructor** inherits from **MyParentConstructor**  :

```
  object1 instanceof MyParentConstructor === true
```

Also, if **MyParentConstructor** inherits from **MyGrandParentConstructor**  :

```
  object1 instanceof MyGrandParentConstructor === true
```

It is evident that all classes inherits from `Object`, thus :

```
  object1 instanceof Object === true
```

Now , What is the code of **parents** method which give us :

```
   MyConstructor.parents() ===[MyParentConstructor,MyGrandParentConstructor,Object]
  HTMLDivElement.parents() === [HTMLElement,Element,Object]
```

Note that [you can create a class inherited from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15399594/747579)

Comment: You may be able to traverse the inheritance chain using [*getPrototypeOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2) and that Object's *constructor* property until you reach *null* (the ultimate `[[Prototype]]`). That will return the Objects, but not necessarily their "names".

Comment: @RobG yep, similar to recursively read `__proto__` property, until get to `null`.